# Windows 7 SP1 breaks access (not the ADO way)

Tags: ms-access, ado, windows-7-x64

So our corporate IT dept has determined that it is time to force SP1 on everyone's PC's.

Which means I need to get my Access 2003 ADE application working with the stupid ADO incompatibility problem.

I got the ADO portion to work by following KB2517589, but now several of my textboxes say #Name?.

These are bound to code, so, for example, the data field in the textbox is =CalcShippingAddr().

As a test, I replaced the code with the following:

```
    Public Function CalcShippingAddr() As String
        msgbox "Func Called"
        CalcShippingAddr = "Test"
    End Function
```

This works fine on my dev machine, but as soon as I make an ADE and send it to a PC without SP1, I get #Name? on the textbox.  The msgbox nevers pops up.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried SP3 re http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270168/calculated-textbox-control-not-showing-value-in-access-2007-but-shows-in-2003/9270275#comment11729873_9270275 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fault to do with the field calculation, I haven't seen it myself but have heard that clicking in to the relevant text box would then show the value although this is not a solution.  I would always recommend using unbound forms as you can control step by step what your fields/objects are doing.  As you already have a custom function to calculate the shipping address then it should be simple enough for you to add the code the the forms 'Open' or 'Load' event e.g.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    textbox = CalcShippingAddr

End Sub
```

Comment: This would work if the form were a single form, but for a continuous form, it would only populate the first field.

Comment: @Scottie Which database are you connecting to with ADO, is it MS Access or a dedicated database server?

Comment: I am not using the native Access database.  I'm linking to a SQL Server database.  As of right now, I'm just not installing Windows 7 SP1 on my dev system.  This seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Scottie The only thing I could think then is to see if you can link your SQL tables and then use the old DAO method rather than ADO.